# Index of treeview root node

Tags: vb.net

I have a treeview in winwoforms.  It has one root and four child nodes.
Using mouseclick event, I need to take index of the selected node but the problem with me is, it displays the index of root node only, even if I click root node or any of the child node, it display index as 0

I want to identify if user clicked the root node or child node.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Index of node is respective to its parent not to whole tree view

Means if nod

```
A – 0
    B – 0
        D – 0
        E – 1
    C - 1
```

EDIT

Write a recursive search to reach to its parent

Each node has object property named parent which is a parent node of that node

```
Public function getTopMostIndex(ByVal trNode as TreeNode) AS Integer
    If trNode.Parent Is Nothing Then
        ‘This is the topmost node
        Return trNode.Index
    Else
        Return getTopMostIndex(trNode)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Please advise how to check if user clicked A or B.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am feeling embarressed to ask you how to call this function.  Calling like Call getTopMostIndex() returns an error

Comment: inside node click event pass node to this index = getTopMostIndex(e.node)